# DynamoDB for an evolving application

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, application-lifecycle

We are considering using DynamoDB as out back end for our new multi-tenant Saas application. This application is still very nascent and will evolve over the next few years. We do not know all the entities yet. The entities we do know also will evolve. Considering these points, is it a good idea to use DynamoDB?

My biggest concern is the fact that we cannot add an LSI for an existing table. So, if my entity were to add a new attribute which needs to be used in a filter, we'd have to create a GSI which costs as much as another table.

Please share your thoughts/experiences in this regard.

Comment: Look into using an overloaded GSI. In a nutshell: you can re-use the same GSI in different ways for different entity types. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html
https://www.trek10.com/blog/dynamodb-single-table-relational-modeling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key consideration with Dyanmo...do you understand how you will need to access the data?

If most of your access will be by key, with a few well defined queries.  Dynamo might be a decent fit.

Here's a useful slide from one of the Dynamo presentations at AWS Summit

[image]